# Configure a device with spi ( Pi Zero )

Tags: linux, usb, debian

I am looking for how I can configure a kernel devices ports, 
I have a MAX3421 usb host shield and I found and compiled the kernel driver for it ( http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/host/max3421-hcd.c?v=4.4 ) But am unable to figure out how to tell the module what ports to use for the spi

- Distro: Raspbian ( Raspberry pi variant of debian )
- Kernel version : 4.9.22+
- module : max3421-hcd

Any help would be greatly appriciated

a link to the shield  https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9947

I also have the ability to take 5v to 3.3

Comment: Could you edit your question to link to the shield and explain how you are planning to use the shield (in broad terms) as I don't understand what it is used for?  Will the (presumably) 5V shield work with the 3V3 Pi GPIO?

Comment: What do you mean by *what ports to use*? MAX3421E seems to have a single USB port and a single SPI interface.

Comment: how does it know which spi port to run over?

Comment: Chatting with some people on FreeNode, they mentioned I have to create a Device Tree binding

Answer (score 0):

From [pinout.xyz](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/spi):

> SPI0 pins in BCM mode are: 9, 10, 11 + 7/8
>
> SPI0 pins in WiringPi are: 12, 13, 14 + 10/11

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.  Please read it again more carefully.